# Python: I get "NotImplementedError:: while trying to use YOLOv8

Tags: python, yolov8

Usually this problem occurs when versions of torch and CUDA are incompatible, but as far as I can tell they are. I use CUDA 12.1 and I installed pytorch using the following command:

```bash
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121
```

(I use windows 10 btw.) Here is a full error message:

```
Freezing layer 'model.22.dfl.conv.weight'
AMP: running Automatic Mixed Precision (AMP) checks with YOLOv8n...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\warle\Desktop\dataset\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1.py", line 7, in <module>
    model.train(data="config.yaml", epochs=120)  # train the model
  File "C:\Users\warle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\model.py", line 338, in train
    self.trainer.train()
  File "C:\Users\warle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\trainer.py", line 190, in train
    self._do_train(world_size)
  File "C:\Users\warle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\trainer.py", line 286, in _do_train
    self._setup_train(world_size)
  File "C:\Users\warle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\trainer.py", line 232, in _setup_train
    self.amp = torch.tensor(check_amp(self.model), device=self.device)
  File "C:\Users\warle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\utils\checks.py", line 607, in check_amp
    assert amp_allclose(YOLO('yolov8n.pt'), im)
  File "C:\Users\warle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\utils\checks.py", line 595, in amp_allclose
    a = m(im, device=device, verbose=False)[0].boxes.data  # FP32 inference
  File "C:\Users\warle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\model.py", line 98, in __call__
    return self.predict(source, stream, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\warle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\model.py", line 239, in predict
    return self.predictor.predict_cli(source=source) if is_cli else self.predictor(source=source, stream=stream)
  File "C:\Users\warle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\predictor.py", line 198, in __call__
    return list(self.stream_inference(source, model, *args, **kwargs))  # merge list of Result into one
  File "C:\Users\warle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\_contextlib.py", line 35, in generator_context
    response = gen.send(None)
  File "C:\Users\warle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\predictor.py", line 269, in stream_inference
    self.results = self.postprocess(preds, im, im0s)
  File "C:\Users\warle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\models\yolo\detect\predict.py", line 25, in postprocess
    preds = ops.non_max_suppression(preds,
  File "C:\Users\warle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\utils\ops.py", line 238, in non_max_suppression
    i = torchvision.ops.nms(boxes, scores, iou_thres)  # NMS
  File "C:\Users\warle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torchvision\ops\boxes.py", line 41, in nms
    return torch.ops.torchvision.nms(boxes, scores, iou_threshold)
  File "C:\Users\warle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\_ops.py", line 692, in __call__
    return self._op(*args, **kwargs or {})
NotImplementedError: Could not run 'torchvision::nms' with arguments from the 'CUDA' backend. This could be because the operator doesn't exist for this backend, or was omitted during the selective/custom build process (if using custom build). If you are a Facebook employee using PyTorch on mobile, please visit https://fburl.com/ptmfixes for possible resolutions. 'torchvision::nms' is only available for these backends: [CPU, QuantizedCPU, BackendSelect, Python, FuncTorchDynamicLayerBackMode, Functionalize, Named, Conjugate, Negative, ZeroTensor, ADInplaceOrView, AutogradOther, AutogradCPU, AutogradCUDA, AutogradXLA, AutogradMPS, AutogradXPU, AutogradHPU, AutogradLazy, AutogradMeta, Tracer, AutocastCPU, AutocastCUDA, FuncTorchBatched, FuncTorchVmapMode, Batched, VmapMode, FuncTorchGradWrapper, PythonTLSSnapshot, FuncTorchDynamicLayerFrontMode, PreDispatch, PythonDispatcher].

CPU: registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\vision\vision\pytorch\vision\torchvision\csrc\ops\cpu\nms_kernel.cpp:112 [kernel]
QuantizedCPU: registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\vision\vision\pytorch\vision\torchvision\csrc\ops\quantized\cpu\qnms_kernel.cpp:124 [kernel]
BackendSelect: fallthrough registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\BackendSelectFallbackKernel.cpp:3 [backend fallback]
Python: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\PythonFallbackKernel.cpp:153 [backend fallback]
FuncTorchDynamicLayerBackMode: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\functorch\DynamicLayer.cpp:498 [backend fallback]
Functionalize: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\FunctionalizeFallbackKernel.cpp:290 [backend fallback]
Named: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\NamedRegistrations.cpp:7 [backend fallback]
Conjugate: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\ConjugateFallback.cpp:17 [backend fallback]
Negative: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\native\NegateFallback.cpp:19 [backend fallback]
ZeroTensor: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\ZeroTensorFallback.cpp:86 [backend fallback]
ADInplaceOrView: fallthrough registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:86 [backend fallback]
AutogradOther: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:53 [backend fallback]
AutogradCPU: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:57 [backend fallback]
AutogradCUDA: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:65 [backend fallback]
AutogradXLA: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:69 [backend fallback]
AutogradMPS: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:77 [backend fallback]
AutogradXPU: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:61 [backend fallback]
AutogradHPU: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:90 [backend fallback]
AutogradLazy: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:73 [backend fallback]
AutogradMeta: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:81 [backend fallback]
Tracer: registered at ..\torch\csrc\autograd\TraceTypeManual.cpp:296 [backend fallback]
AutocastCPU: fallthrough registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\autocast_mode.cpp:382 [backend fallback]
AutocastCUDA: fallthrough registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\autocast_mode.cpp:249 [backend fallback]
FuncTorchBatched: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\functorch\LegacyBatchingRegistrations.cpp:710 [backend fallback]
FuncTorchVmapMode: fallthrough registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\functorch\VmapModeRegistrations.cpp:28 [backend fallback]
Batched: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\LegacyBatchingRegistrations.cpp:1075 [backend fallback]
VmapMode: fallthrough registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\VmapModeRegistrations.cpp:33 [backend fallback]
FuncTorchGradWrapper: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\functorch\TensorWrapper.cpp:203 [backend fallback]
PythonTLSSnapshot: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\PythonFallbackKernel.cpp:161 [backend fallback]
FuncTorchDynamicLayerFrontMode: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\functorch\DynamicLayer.cpp:494 [backend fallback]
PreDispatch: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\PythonFallbackKernel.cpp:165 [backend fallback]
PythonDispatcher: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\PythonFallbackKernel.cpp:157 [backend fallback]
```

What I tried to achieve: I am trying to train a model using YOLOv8 to recognize animals in the picture. The problem was that the training process would take many hours,and I have few more models to train, so I tried to speed the process up with my gpu. After installing cuda and new pytorch version nothing works at all.